# "I asked Tara if she wanted to go …"

Tags: tense

*After my Pilates class last night **I asked Tara if she wanted to go to the cinema with me one night next week, then if she’d cover for me**.*

Why is in the first part of the bold passage used after "if" the past tense ("wanted") and in the second one out of the tense shift "would"? Would it be possible: I asked Tara if she would want…

Comment: We use the past tense forms to talk about the future in clauses with if when making suggestions about what might happen, for example: If we invited John, then Mary would bring Ann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of reported speech. What "I" actually said was these two sentences:

```
Do you want to go to the cinema with me one night next week?
Would you please cover for me?
```

When you convert it to reported speech, you put the modals into the past. 'want to' is a modal auxiliary: it has a past 'wanted to'. 'would' is a proper modal, so the past is the same as the present- 'would'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider these sentences:
 *'I am asking Tara if she wants to go to the cinema with me.' 'I am also asking Tara if she will cover for me.'*

Convert them to past : *want - wanted, will - would*

And combining these two sentences, you get the original one.

Surely, *'I am asking Tara if she will want to go to the cinema with me'* sounds unnatural here.